# Why can't the result of strerror() be returned

Tags: c, casting, strerror

According to the man page `strerror(errnum)` returns a `char *`, but I get the following warning:

```
gcc temp.c -o temp
temp.c: In function ‘mystrerror’:
temp.c:10:4: warning: return makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

I get a segfault When I run it with `./temp 0` but not `./temp 256`.

Could someone explain why this happens and how to fix it (if possible)?

### temp.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>

char *mystrerror(int errnum)
{
    switch (errnum) {
    case 256:
        return "My test";
    default:
        return strerror(errnum);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int err;

    if (argc > 1) {
        err = atoi(argv[1]);
        printf("test error (%d) %s\n", err, mystrerror(err));
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you include `#include <string.h>` and tried?

Comment: I don't remember off the top of my head; will -Wall warn you that you're using an undeclared function in C?

Comment: also `#include <stdlib.h>` for `atoi`

Comment: @Wug It definitely does.

Comment: `gcc -Wall temp.c` `warning: implicit declaration of function ‘strerror’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

Comment: -Wall saves the day again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the inclusion of the `<string.h>` header file.

[Documentation.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695299/functions/strerror.html)

The compiler even tells you what **exactly** your problem is:

> return makes pointer from integer without a cast

If there's no prototype present for a function, then it's assumed to return `int`. And it appears that on your platform, a pointer to `char` does not fit into an `int`, hence its truncated, and then `printf()` tries to dereference the thus invalid pointer.

Comment: Well, if you're interested what **exactly** the problem is, use `-Wall`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath One **does always** use `-Wall`. (And I use `-Wextra -pedantic -pedantic-errors` as well, but maybe I'm just masochistic.)

Comment: Actually C99 dropped the default `int` rule; calling a function with no visible declaration is just illegal (actually a constraint violation). But many compilers, including gcc, operate under the old rules by default.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, that's correct, both `gcc` and `clang` refuse to issue a diagnostic unless `-std=c99 -pedantic` is present, actually.

Comment: Software would have a lot fewer bugs if they made this a fatal error except when `-std=c89` is specified.

Answer (score 4):

According to the strerror manpage its include is `#include <string.h>`.

Without a function definition C assumes every function returns int, which is why you are getting that compiler error.